# Can't submit app with CorePlot using Xcode4

Tags: xcode4, app-store, core-plot, ipa

I created an application in XCode 4 that uses Core Plot. 
I installed Core plot as an aditional SDK following the instructions from here:http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications (Install SDK)
The instructions for "static Library" haven't been updated yet fro XCode 4.

I can run the app in the simulator, install it on my iPhone and everything works just ok. I was even able to send it to beta testers using several services like TestFlight. For this, I had to generate an archive and then "share" by generating the .ipa file. No single problem here.

Now, when I try to validate/submit the app I got this error:
[image]

I'm selecting the "distribution" configuration, then product -> archive, then in the Organizer I try "validate" or "submit", but I always get this same result.

I also made sure that the "skip install" is set to NO. This part is confusion, Apple says it should be YES and many posts here say it should be NO. If I set it to YES, the app is not even archived.

At this point I'm not even sure if the issue is the "skip install" flag or core plot. I found this question: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=280, so I think my issue may be related.

If I open the archive file, this is what is inside:
[image]
[image]

Any ideas/suggestions will be truly appreciated.

Comment: no way to do it using Code4? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475527/xcode-4-file-not-found-when-creating-ipa-with-core-plot-library

Comment: I just updated Xcode to 4.0.2..... same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for both TestFlight and App Store.
The solution for me was to archive the app, and in the organizer select "Don't sign" when you try to validate/submit or share (in the case of TestFlight).

Hope this helps.