# Copy CoreData source into XCode 4 project

Tags: iphone, xcode4, core-plot

I'm trying to compile an iPhone app that uses CorePlot. I'm using XCode 4.
I already ask for a question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758653/cant-submit-app-with-coreplot-using-xcode4) but no answers yet.

Is there a way to copy all the source code into my project and don't use additional SKDs or static libraries?

I just download the latest version of core plot using Mercurial, and copied the content of the "iPhoneOnly", "Source", "TestResources" folders and the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file. Then I executed this python file: CPNumericData+TypeConversions_Generation.py
I have couple of warnings and this error:
error: CorePlotProbes.h: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to copy the source code into the project. I got it working using CorePlot as SDK. Please see my other answer to your first question: [Can't submit app with CorePlot using Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758653/cant-submit-app-with-coreplot-using-xcode4)